# Clever Tap Push Notification Sound Issue

Tags: ios, objective-c, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

Even to play default Push Notification sound I have to send "Default" value against sound file Key in Clever Tap Dashboard.

[image]

Is is necessary to send default even if I don't want any custom sound.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per the apple documentation & guidelines if you want to play default sound than you must have to send "Default" value in sound file. Other wise it will not play default sound.

For custom sound you can pass custom sound file name in place of default.

**Edit :**

- In case of custom sound your sound file should be exist in your xcode project in resources.
- Make sure your custom sound file duration no longer than 30 seconds. Otherwise it will play default sound.
- Also you need to add that custom file name with title `UILocalNotificationDefaultSoundName` into `info.plist`. See below image :

[image]

Hope it will help you.

Comment: then that file should exists in our project in order to play custom sound ?